# An L1 entity type and an L3 entity type having the same label

Tags: configuration, master-data-management, reltio

In Reltio, can I give a label to an entity type in L3 configuration that is already present in L1 configuration?

For example, we know that Individual is an entity type in L1 configuration. So, can I make an Individual entity type in L3 configuration? Also, if it is possible, can I extend L3 configuration's Individual from L1 configuration's Individual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the label of any entity type in your L3.

Also, you can extend any entity type in your L3 by just adding your custom attributes.  Do not include the attributes or properties in your L3 that you are not changing.  They will automatically be inherited in your L3.

Example:

```
 {
  "uri": "configuration",
  "description": "ABC Company Customer Hub",
  "referenceConfigurationURI": "configuration/_vertical/life-sciences",
  "entityTypes": [
    {
      "uri": "configuration/entityTypes/Individual",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "uri": "configuration/entityTypes/Individual/attributes/Prefix",
          "lookupCode": "rdm/lookupTypes/Prefix"
        },
        {
          "uri":
       "configuration/entityTypes/Individual/attributes/AbcGoodCustomerFlag",
          "label": "ABC Good Customer",
          "name": "AbcGoodCustomerFlag",
          "type": "Boolean",
          "Default": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above example, 100’s of Reltio’s standard attributes are automatically “pulled into” the entity type via the inheritance like:

```
"referenceConfigurationURI": "configuration/_vertical/life-sciences"
```

Along with established life-sciences best practices and configuration including matching, survivorship, etc.

Additionally, it adds a Reltio RDM lookup to the already-defined prefix attribute and adds a custom attribute called "ABC Good Customer".

Again, the result of these few lines will be a complete configuration, not just the custom items mentioned. So, you just need to add your customizations in L3.

Comment: Welcome to [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please use formatting tools within post form to make your post more readable.